# Multiple AFHTTPRequestOperations that has dependency of each other

Tags: concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, afnetworking-2

What I trying to achieve is send two request to the server which orders are matter,and the second request's parameters is unknown until the first request result comes back.

I already tring as the following code snippet using the afnetworking2.0

```
NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

NSMutableURLRequest*request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWuthURL@"URLSTRING"];

// configure the request with parameters 

[request setHTTPBody:JsonData]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
[operation setComplemetionBlockWithSucess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responsObject)
{ 
    //parse the result using NSXMLParser;
    NSInteger result=weakSelf.parseRule.identifier;

}
failure :^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"fail");    
}];

NSMutableURLRequest*secondRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWuthURL@"URLSTRING"];

//Using the first request result to set the parameters in second request

[secondRequest setHTTPBody:JsonData]; 
[secondRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* secondOperation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:secondRequest];
[secondOperation setComplemetionBlockWithSucess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responsObject)
{ 
   //do something

}
failure :^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"fail");    
}];

[secondOperation addDependency:Operation];
[queue addOPerations:@[operation,secondOperation]];
```

Which didn't work, I can get back the first operation result correctly,but the thing is that my second request params setting is execute before the result comes back.Any advice will be really appreciated.
Should I use the dispatch_semaphore? Or Any other suggestion?